# Pass more than 4-channel data to OpenGL or Vulkan

Tags: opengl, textures, vulkan

I would like to pass the following values as a texture to the fragment shader:

- Base R
- Base G
- Base B
- Material switch (metal/dielectric)
- Normal x
- Normal y
- Normal z
- IOR (Only for dielectric)
- Roughness

That is a lot of stuff. It looks like this would require three different textures in OpenGL. Questions:

- Are there any extensions to OpenGL that makes it possible to pass this as one texture?
- From what I have understood about Vulkan, GPU memory is more easily accessible. Does this mean that you can use generalized texture formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in Vulkan, you can not have more than a four channels for a texture. However, both in OpenGL and Vulkan, you could use a 32 bits by channels texture, and use something like `packUnorm`( https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/packUnorm.xhtml ). But it works only with integer texture and you will have to perform filtering by yourself

Another way could be to use something like SSBO ou TBO. But I do not understand what the problem is by using 3 textures.

Comment: "But I do not understand what the problem is by using 3 textures." I guessed that it could improve performance by reducing the number of glTex* calls.

Comment: @user877329: You're not going to call `glTex…` all the time. Also when it comes to textures your primary bottleneck is memory and/or bus bandwidth, not number of API calls.

Comment: You could also use a 3D texture.

Comment: @dari Yes but you have to be careful. Else you will have a filtering between slice. However, array texture why not

Comment: If you want to avoid changing texture bindings every draw, use bindless textures.